# Awk printf number in width and round it up

Tags: scripting, awk, printf

I need to **printf** a number out, but with given width and rounded (with awk!)

```
%10s
```

I have this and somehow I need to connect the `%d` but everything I do, ends up with too much parametres for awk (because I have more columns).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%3.0f\n", 3.6}'
  4
```

Our format option has two parts:

- `3`: meaning output will be padded to 3 characters.
- `.0f`: meaning output will have no precision, meaning rounded up.

From `man awk`, you can see more details:

```
width   The field should be padded to this width. The field is normally padded
        with spaces. If the 0  flag  has  been  used, it is padded with zeroes.

.prec   A number that specifies the precision to use when printing.  For the %e,
        %E, %f and %F, formats, this specifies the number of digits you want
        printed to the right of the decimal point. For the %g, and %G formats,
        it specifies the maximum number of significant  digits. For the %d, %o,
        %i, %u, %x, and %X formats, it specifies the minimum number of digits to
        print. For %s, it specifies the maximum number of characters from the
        string that should be printed.
```

Comment: The rounding with `%3.0f` is round-to-nearest-ties-to-even. Not *rounded up* as you say.

Answer (score 16):

Using the `%f` format specifier, your (floating point) number will get automatically rounded as you specify.  For example, to round a value to whole numbers use

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { printf("%.0f\n", 1.49); }'
1
$ awk 'BEGIN { printf("%.0f\n", 1.5); }'
2
```

If you want further trailing digits, just change precision.

Comment: This is wrong: it rounds towards the closest even number. Consider `awk 'BEGIN { printf("%.0f\n", 2.5) }'` ==> `2` rather than `3`

Answer (score 8):

Awk uses sprintf underneath and it does unbiased rounding, so depending on your platform if you want it to ALWAYS round up you may need to use something like this:

`awk "BEGIN { x+=(5/2); printf('%.0f', (x == int(x)) ? x : int(x)+1) }"`

Not realizing this can lead to subtle but nasty bugs.