# How to round to 2 decimals in bash like MS Excel does?

Tags: bash, numeric-data, excel

I spent hours in searching how to round "floating numbers" in BASH but couldn't find any correct! solution :( If I put these numbers to Excel, then I will receive the correct results after rounding to 2 decimals:

```
3.314 -> 3.31
3.315 -> 3.32
8.124 -> 8.12
8.125 -> 8.13
```

How to have the exact results in BASH? I tried with `printf` and `awk` but don't have the same result

```
prompt> printf '%.*f\n' 2 8.125
8.12
prompt> echo '8.125' | awk '{printf("%.2f\n", $1)}'
8.12
```

Comment: You seem to believe there is one single correct way of rounding numbers (the Excel way, which many of us know nothing about). This [is wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding). What about negative numbers?

Comment: @xhienne first focus on non negative numbers, at least for them I need program that rounds me numbers in the same way I was taught in Elementary school when I was 10years old... is that a big deal? next digit is `0,1,2,3,4->down, 5,6,7,8,9->up`

Comment: It's already been [explained why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/759419/100397) you get the answers you do. And that was answered (by me) and then you were posted to a duplicate explaining in better detail. This now is a different question and I'm sure you'll get an answer, but it would probably help if you explained that you want rounding up rather than bankers' rounding

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184554/100397

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your system uses GNU coreutils then the [numfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html) command should be available, and allows you to choose between rounding ‘up’, ‘down’, ‘from-zero’ (the default), ‘towards-zero’, or ‘nearest’.

For example (here in a locale where the decimal radix character is `.`):

```
$ numfmt --round=nearest --format %.2f << EOF
3.314
3.315
8.124
8.125
EOF
3.31
3.32
8.12
8.13
```

Comment: But then see `echo 10000.185 | numfmt --round=nearest --format %.2f` (on a GNU/Linux amd64 computer)

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong here?... now I'm totally confused... I assumed that level tenThousand is not such a big number not to be able to work with.. :(

Comment: @user3719454 see my answer

Comment: We don't have to go to high numbers. `numfmt --round=nearest --format %.2f 0.265` outputs 0.26. Looking at the code, it does the exact same thing as [@ChrisDavies' answer](/a/759757), though adapted to support negative numbers as well.

Answer (score 16):

> ```
> printf '%.2f\n' 8.125
> ```

Will convert that `8.125` textual representation of a decimal number to an internal binary representation using something like the standard `strtod()` or `strtold()` C functions, getting a `double` or `long double` binary floating point number whose internal representation will depend on the C compiler and computer architecture.

Then that number will be passed by the `printf` command to the `printf()` standard function (or a variant thereof that returns the result into a string), which will convert it back to a textual decimal representation and do the rounding. That rounding rounds to nearest, half to even (also called *banker's rounding*).

The method you learnt in school has a bias as it tends to on average overestimate (for positive numbers). With half to even, both `8.125` and `8.115` are rounded to `8.12` (the `2` being *even*), one rounding down, one rounding up. With half those numbers rounded down and the other half rounded up, on a large number of numbers, you don't introduce a systematic bias.

Now, that only applies for numbers that can be represented exactly in binary.

As it happens, 8.125 can be represented in binary. That's 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>-3</sup>. 8.135 cannot. The IEEE 754 double precision binary number closest to that is 8.1349999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625 (when converted back to decimal), and so it will be converted to 8.13, as it's nearest, not to even (8.14).

So to do what you want (or even to do proper banker rounding), you need something that doesn't work in binary, but works in decimal. So anything that uses `printf()` underneath including the `printf` utility, `awk`'s `printf()`, or more generally work with the processor floating point arithmetic capabilities that work with binary numbers including `numfmt` is out of the question.

You could use for instance `python3`'s `decimal` module (as [shown by @marcelm](/a/759900)) or `perl`'s [`Math::BigFloat` module](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::BigFloat) and [its `bfround()` function](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::BigFloat#bfround-(-$scale-)). By default, they do *banker's rounding*:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1.1{0..5}5 | perl -MMath::BigFloat -lne 'print "$_ -> " . Math::BigFloat->new($_)->bfround(-2)'
1.105 -> 1.10
1.115 -> 1.12
1.125 -> 1.12
1.135 -> 1.14
1.145 -> 1.14
1.155 -> 1.16
```

But you can switch to the `common` *mode* which matches the one you learnt in school:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {-,}1.1{0..5}5 +825e-3 0xAAp-6 0x1p100 nan Infinity | 
   perl -MMath::BigFloat -lne '
     print "$_ -> " . Math::BigFloat->new($_)->bfround(-2,common)'
-1.105 -> -1.11
-1.115 -> -1.12
-1.125 -> -1.13
-1.135 -> -1.14
-1.145 -> -1.15
-1.155 -> -1.16
1.105 -> 1.11
1.115 -> 1.12
1.125 -> 1.13
1.135 -> 1.14
1.145 -> 1.15
1.155 -> 1.16
+825e-3 -> 0.83
0xAAp-6 -> 2.66
0x1p100 -> 1267650600228229401496703205376.00
nan -> NaN
Infinity -> inf
```

(Showing extra numbers expressed using different notations).

Note that like `python3`'s approach, but unlike `numfmt` and some `printf` utility implementations, that is not locale-sensitive. In particular the decimal radix character will be `.` for both input and output even in locales where it's otherwise `,` or `٫`.

Comment: `bfround(-2)` because we round to units of 10^-2, right?

Comment: @ilkkachu, I've added links to  the doc. *bfround ( -$scale )  Rounds to the $scale'th place right from the '.', counting from the dot.*

Answer (score 0):

A standard approach for rounding to an integer is to add ½ and truncate:

```
printf '%s\n' 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 |
    awk '{ print int($1 +.5) }'
```

To achieve two decimal places multiply by 100, truncate, and divide again:

```
printf '%s\n' 3.314 3.315 8.124 8.125 |
    awk '{ print int(100*$1 +.5)/100 }'
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' 3.314 3.315 8.124 8.125 |
    awk '{ printf "%0.2f\n", int(100*$1 +.5)/100 }'
```

Comment: floor or `trunc(x + 0.5)` doesn't round correctly for all inputs when using binary floating point (like Awk does).  If `x` is 1 ulp smaller than 0.5, `x+0.5` will round up to 1.0, even though `x < 0.5`.  This is an old bad approach that used to get used in languages that didn't provide anything better, but these days is fairly well known to not work for all input values unless you use decimal floating-point.  See discussion on [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/30232021)

Comment: This is less bad than directly adding `0.005` and printing 2 decimal places, though.  That answer is super broken, and `0.005` isn't even exactly representable as a float or double (https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).  With adding `0.5` only failing for one bit-pattern for `x`, doing `100 * x` might not be able to produce that bit-pattern.  OTOH, `100 * x` might itself have some rounding error since `100` isn't a power of 2, so it's not just scaling the exponent.  So I expect there are some values this will round incorrectly.

Comment: It might be good enough if you want to avoid perl and just use tools like awk, though, but your answer should definitely mention the numerical problems with this method.

Comment: Would be worth pointing out it doesn't work for negative numbers

Comment: Also note that awk's default OFMT is `%.6g` so it doesn't work for numbers greater than 10000.

Comment: Note that the OP seems to  want a `%.2f`-like behaviour where 1.0003 becomes `1.00`. You'll see that `echo 10000.175 | awk '{ printf "%.2f\n", int(100*$1 +.5)/100 }'` gives 10000.17 (10000.2 with `print`)

Answer (score 0):

No printf, no perl, just text manipulation

```
round2() {
  main=$(echo "$1" | sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{0,2})[0-9]*/\1/g')
  lastDigit="${main: -1}"
  remainder="${1//$main/}"
  
  if [ -z "$remainder" ]; then
    echo $main
    return
  fi
  remFirst="${remainder:0:1}"

  if [ "$remFirst" -ge 5 ] && ! [ "$remFirst" -eq 5 -a $((lastDigit % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    main_no_decimal=$(echo "$main" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)/\1\2/')
    main_no_decimal=$((main_no_decimal + 1))
    main="${main_no_decimal%??}.${main_no_decimal: -2}"
  fi

  echo $main 
}

round2 5.1
round2 9
round2 3.314
round2 3.315
round2 8.124
round2 8.125
round2 7.205
round2 1.105
round2 1.115
round2 1.125
round2 1.135
round2 1.145
round2 1.155
round2 100000.185
```

Test output

```
5.1
9
3.31
3.32
8.12
8.12
7.20
1.10
1.12
1.12
1.14
1.14
1.16
100000.18
```

Comment: Incorrect result for some cases when the input has more than 1 excess digit.  `round2 3.3251` rounds down to `3.32`, but `3.33` is closer to the original value (because of the non-zero digits following the 5) so it wasn't a tie-break situation.  In banker's rounding, round-to-even is only for a tie-break when the input is exactly half-way between two possible output values.

Comment: Also, the OP seems to be specifying in the question that they want a trailing `5` to always round up, not banker's rounding (nearest with even as a tie-break).  IDK if they changed their mind about this in comments, but your answer doesn't address the fact that it correctly rounds `8.125` to `8.12` when the question requests `8.13` for that case.  So I think you're trying to implement banker's rounding, and should say so because there are many different possible rounding strategies, and this isn't the one the question as written asks for.

Comment: Would be worth noting that it doesn't work for negative numbers.

Comment: Also note that using unsanitised data in bash arithmetic expressions introduces arbitrary command execution vulnerabilities, so your `round2` may end up call `perl` after all if called as `round2 '5.12+a[$(perl)]-1'` for instance (the missing quotes around some of the expansions introduce at least a DoS vulnerability as usual as well).

Comment: Fair feedback folks, thank you. I think all the issues mentioned could be handled pretty easily, but if its not a popular solution then there's nothing to gain by fleshing it out. If the OP is interested then I'd be happy to rewrite it with the feedback accounted for

Answer (score 0):

### Using Python

```
python3 -c 'import decimal, sys; print(round(decimal.Decimal(sys.argv[1]), ndigits=2))' 3.314
```

Python's `Decimal` represents a base-10 decimal number exactly with unlimited¹ precision, without the floating point accuracy issues most other answers suffer from.

In [`decimal`'s DefaultContext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.DefaultContext) Python's `round()` rounds half values towards even (known as banker's rounding), which is the generally preferred rounding method as it does not introduce a bias.

Example outputs:

```
3.314      ->  3.31
3.315      ->  3.32
8.124      ->  8.12
8.125      ->  8.12
10000.195  ->  10000.20
```

You can also round halves away from 0 as in your desired behaviour with:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; from decimal import *; getcontext().rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP; print(round(Decimal(sys.argv[1]),2))' 8.125
8.13
```

Which will round 8.125 to 8.13 and -8.125 to -8.13.

Increase the value of `getcontect().prec` (defaults to 28), if you need to handle numbers that could round to 10<sup>26</sup> or greater (or -10<sup>26</sup> or smaller).

See [the `decimal` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) for details.

---

<sup>¹ determined by the [context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#context-objects)'s `prec`/`Emin`/`Emax` which [have very large if not infinite maximum values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.MAX_PREC)</sup>

Comment: To whoever downvoted: why?